# send an image (optional) with message subject and body?

Tags: php, mysql, message

I've created a simple php messaging system for users to send and receive messages to each other. What i want to try and do is add in an optional image input field so the user can choose an image and send this as part of their message?

The photo would need to store in a directory folder on my server and the name of the image will need to be stored in mysql table along with the rest of the message fields i.e. content, subject, image_name.

Can someone show me how i could adapt my code to upload an image with the form please?

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
  <?php 

// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    require('includes/_config/connection.php');
// LOAD FUNCTIONS
    require('includes/functions.php');
// GET IP ADDRESS
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


?>


  <?php require_once("includes/sessionframe.php"); 
?>


  <?php


    confirm_logged_in();




    if (isset ($_GET['to'])) {
    $user_to_id = $_GET['to'];

}


?> 
  <?php 
//We check if the form has been sent
if(isset($_POST['subject'], $_POST['message_content']))
{
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $content = $_POST['message_content'];
    $image = $POST ['image'];

        //We remove slashes depending on the configuration
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
                $subject = stripslashes($subject);
                $content = stripslashes($content);
                $image = stripslashes($image);

        }


        //We check if all the fields are filled
        if($_POST['subject']!='' and $_POST['message_content']!='')
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_messages (id, from_user_id, to_user_id, subject, content, image) VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$user_to_id."', '".$subject."', '".$content."', '".$image."');";
            mysql_query($sql, $connection);

            echo "<div class=\"infobox2\">The message has successfully been sent.</div>";
        }
}


if(!isset($_POST['subject'], $_POST['message_content']))

if (empty($_POST['subject'])){
        $errors[] = 'The subject cannot be empty.';

    if (empty($_POST['body'])){
        $errors[] = 'The body cannot be empty.';

    }
    }

{
?>


<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <div class="subject">
  <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">

   <input type="file" name="image" id="image">

    <textarea name="message_content" id="message_content" cols="50" placeholder="Message" rows="8" style="resize:none; height: 100px;"></textarea>

    <input type="image" src="assets/img/icons/loginarrow1.png" name="send_button" id="send_button" value="Send">

</form>

<?php } ?>

<?php ob_end_flush() ?>
```

Comment: As a one hint, You have to add the following attribute to your form: enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just did some digging on Google and found this code. I think this should do what you want, but of course you will have to adapt it for your instance.

```
<?php
  $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
  $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
  if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
      && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
      && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
           if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
             echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
           }  else{
                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
                echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
                echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
                echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
           if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
             echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
           }   else{
                 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                 "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                 echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
               }
           }
   }  else  {
        echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```